# Main Menu Editor gone

Tags: pi-4, troubleshooting, raspberry-pi-os-buster

So I had my pi 4 for a few weeks now and everything was working fine.
Suddenly, the main menu editor is missing and I can't seem to restore it.
[image]
I tried starting it via 'alacarte' but nothing happens. It's missing even when I log in as the root user. Is there a way I can reinstall it again without having to reinstall the whole OS again?

OS:
I'm using Raspberry OS v 10 buster